APT update error while building docker image
Here is the relevant lines of Dockerfile that I am using to build an image:
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby33:3.0.5

ENV HOME /root

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential git vim pkg-config ldap-utils default-mysql-client default-libmysqlclient-dev curl

...

Command used to build the image:
$ docker-compose build

And the error seen is:
Step 3/18 : RUN apt-get update -qq &&     apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential git vim pkg-config ldap-utils default-mysql-client default-libmysqlclient-dev curl
 ---> Running in 38bf40e8c8cf
W: https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger/dists/jammy/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success '/usr/bin/test -e /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.PackageKit.service && /usr/bin/test -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket && /usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.PackageKit --object-path /org/freedesktop/PackageKit --timeout 4 --method org.freedesktop.PackageKit.StateHasChanged cache-update > /dev/null; /bin/echo > /dev/null'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code

